# Как распарсить файл формата .trk на байты в Java?

Tags: java, android, byte

Есть моделька ноты с соответствующими ей полями. Из этих нот сделана музыкальная дорожка, судя по всему у нее формат файла `MIDI`. Сама музыкальная дорожка перекодирована в формат `.trk`.
Данный файл формата `.trk` нужно распарсить на байты и просетать их в поля ноты. Потом просетать поля следующей ноты и так далее пока дорожка не закончится. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: Описание формата у вас уже есть?

Comment: Если данные в файле с расширением .trk записаны в каком-нибудь читабельном виде (например через запятую 1,2,6,17,2) то можно попробовать прочитать вручную. А если данные имеют какой-то специфический формат, то это получается нетривиальная задача и придётся искать алгоритм конвертирования в понятный вид. Возможно есть библиотека. Итак что внутри файла?

Comment: Если данные в файле с расширением .trk записаны в каком-нибудь читабельном виде (например через запятую 1,2,6,17,2) то можно попробовать прочитать вручную. А если данные имеют какой-то специфический формат, то это получается нетривиальная задача и придётся искать алгоритм конвертирования в понятный вид. Возможно есть библиотека. Итак что внутри файла?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Байты файла можно получить с помощью библиотеки `commons-io`:

```
dependencies {
    compile "commons-io:commons-io:+"
}
```

С помощью кода:

```
private byte[] loadBytes() {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[0];

    try {
        InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(backgroundFile);
        try {
            bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileInputStream);
        } finally {
            fileInputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        AppLog.printError(e);
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: Не используйте в качестве версии либы `+`. Это может привести к серьёзным проблемам при смене апи библиотеки в новой версии

Answer (score 3):

Прочитать файл в массив байт можно стандартными средствами Java без использования библиотек:

```
public static @NonNull byte[] load(@NonNull File file) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        int size = fis.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        fis.read(buffer);
        return buffer;
    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
    }
}
```